# Regexpression - how to find subgroups in strings

Tags: regex, grep

I have

```
[1] "000010004" "011120000" "002030000" "000300020" "003000020" "001000040" "000030020" "000010112"

[9] "050000000" "000000041" "001020020" "001030001" "001000130" "000000050" "000120020" "000500000"
```

using grep I want to find all groups (string inside "" is a group) that contain

a. subgroup 2,3 (means: ...2...3... and  ...3...2...)

b. subgroup 1, 1, 1, 2 (means: ...1...1...1...2 and 1...1...2...1... etc etc)

Order doesnt matter, but frequency does. Meaning for a) 2 and 3 each should just appear once.

thanks for help

Comment: Can you elaborate on what a subgroup is? Do you want to find the pattern `1,2` in the input string?

Comment: You mean the position within a string, or the position of a string containing the numbers within a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a regular expression using lookahead but isn't really pretty:

For example to match a quoted number that contains exactly one `2` and one `3` you could do this (verbose regex used for readability):

```
"         # quote
(?=       # Assert that the following can be matched:
 [^\D2]*  # zero or more numbers except 2
 2        # 2
 [^\D2]*  # zero or more numbers except 2
 "        # quote
)         # End of lookahead
(?=[^\D3]*3[^\D3]*") # same for the number 3
(\d+)     # one or more digits, capture the result
"         # quote
```

To match exactly three `1`s and one `2`:

```
"         # quote
(?=       # Assert that the following can be matched:
 (?:      # Match the following group:
  [^\D1]* # zero or more numbers except 1
  1       # 1
 ){3}     # exactly three times.
 [^\D1]*  # Match zero or more numbers except 1
 "        # quote
)         # End of lookahead
(?=[^\D2]*2[^\D2]*") # as above
(\d+)     # one or more digits, capture the result
"         # quote
```

I don't know if this will work with standard `grep`.

Comment: it works with `grep -P`, although of course you’d have to embed a `(?x)` for expanded/expressive/excellent:) mode.

Answer (score 0):

I assume with `a. numbers 2,3` you want to match following entries of the input array

```
[3] "002030000"
[4] "000300020"
[5] "003000020"
[7] "000030020"
```

and with `b. numbers 1, 1, 1,2` you want to match following entries

```
[2] "011120000"
[8] "000010112"
```

to check for frequency you'd probably need some regex with lookaround. This is rather complicated if possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not possible with `grep` alone.

But you may do the following:

1. Find all groups (quoted things)

   Make sets out of them

   Compare your input against these sets.

It's trivial in `awk`.